# Indentation of preprocessor statements in C

Tags: c, vim, indentation, c-preprocessor, code-formatting

I am writing a program in **C** which should act differently based on the definition or not of symbolic constant(s). For a simple example, my first thought would be to write it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TEST

int main(void) {
   int num;
   #ifdef TEST
      num=1;
      printf("YES\n");
   #else
      num=0;
      printf("NO\n");
   #endif
   printf("%d\n", num);
   return 0;
}
```

However, upon trying to auto-indent my code (specifically by using `gg=G` in vim) my indentation was lost:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TEST

int main(void) {
   int num;
   #ifdef TEST
   num=1;
   printf("YES\n");
   #else
   num=0;
   printf("NO\n");
   #endif
   printf("%d\n", num);
   return 0;
}
```

Of course, if I try to auto-indent something like the following (with actual commands in between) chaos ensues:

```
#ifdef TEST1
   commands
   #ifdef TEST2
      commands
   #else
      #ifdef TEST3
         commands
      #endif
      commands
   #endif
#endif
```

So, is there anything I can do to have the indentation above be treated as the default?

Comment: Preprocessor directives are not executed the program structure, thus you should not indent such conditinally compiled (not the same as conditional code!) code. Nor should you indent the directives themselves. Just start from column 1.

Comment: note: `#else #ifdef X` is translating to`#elif defined(X)`

Comment: Yes indent your code yourself. There is no need to depend on an editor for that and IMHO it's a bad habit that makes lazy. You don't spend that much time indenting your code.

Comment: @iharob I am, indeed, a beginner programmer but I wonder: Why would getting used to auto-indenting be a bad habit? I mean, isn't it one of the reasons that people use text editors for?

Comment: You can use auto indent just fine, don't get used to the editor indenting th code for you. Not everyone likes preprocessor macros indentation, so that might be the reason why your *vim* is behaving like that. You can try with more sophisticated editors in the code formatting sense, *vim* however is great to edit code because of the mechanics of edition.

Comment: The bad habit is using the preprocessor, not getting used to auto-indenting. Had you defined `test` as a `static const bool`, and used an ordinary `if` statement, auto-indentation would have worked fine, and the compiler would have optimized away the check. So what's not to like?

Comment: @rici My question arose while I was solving part of an exercise that explicitly required the use of preprocessor statements. Should I be freely writing the program myself I would have most definitely avoided using them.

Comment: @Ch0sen: that's fine, but it doesn't make it a priority for whoever writes auto-indenting functions :-). FWIW, I personally do indent my preprocessor directives (but not the `#`), but independently of the non-preprocessor lines they enclose. That's what GNU indent will do for you if you provide the `-ppi 2` option (for some value of 2). That doesn't help you while you type, but ideally you won't be typing enough preprocessor commands for it to matter. If you wanted the contents to be auto-indented, put them in a `{`..`}` block.

Comment: ... and feel free to pass on my earlier comment to whoever gave you that exercise :) The preprocessor has its uses, but there are a lot fewer than there used to be, and the example you give is not one of them IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: auto-indentation on editors follow established language guidelines, and what you are trying to do is not considered 'good practice' and thus has not been implemented in any editor (that I've seen at least).

Longer answer: The C language does not have any indentation rules, so any indentation done is by established practice. And different people have different opinions on what their ideal of established practice is. Specifically for preprocessor conditionals, I have never seen anyone use any additional depth - and IMO that would be bad practice as it would get terribly confusing when intermixed with the language conditionals (i.e. if (code))
Take a look at these 2 basic examples:

```
    if (conditional1)
        action1();
#if compileoption1
        else if (conditional2)
            action2();
#else
        action3();
#endif
```

and

```
#if compileoption1
    if (conditional1)
#endif
    action1();
```

It becomes downright impossible to follow the logic through indentation. The pre-processor and the actual compiler are independent steps, and the pre-processor step pays no attention to actual C semantics so conditionals can start and end in places completely orthogonal to the C flow control statements (if, while, for, etc...), making it difficult to try to unify them through something like indentation. Which is in my opinion why it has become standard practice to not use indentation for preprocessor conditionals.
For some well established conventions see the kernel coding guidelines:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

Chapter 20 deals with conditional compilation.